# disable dropdownlist items

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to disable every fifth item in a dropdownlist.

```
dropdownlist1.items[i].Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");
```

How do I write the logic to disable every fifth item in a Dropdownlist?

I am using two `for` loops: one for displaying items and one for disabling items in dropdownlist. How can I simplify my code?

Comment: for(i=0;I<50;i++)
{
 if(i%5==0)
  dropdownlist1.items[i].Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");
 else
  //do nothing and enable the the data
  dropdownlist1.items[i].Attributes.Add("enabled","enabled");
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should consider just not showing them? 
As in:

```
if (i % 5 > 0) {
   dropdownlist1.items[i].Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't "hide" them, but greys them out and keeps them from being selectable - just like the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
 {
    if(c is dropdownlist)
    {
        dropdownlist dl = (dropdownlist)c;
        if (i % 5 > 0)
        {
           dl.items[i].Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");
        }
    }
 }
```

Check this out! same as castirng.

findout all dropdownlist on the form and
on every dropdown list it will disable.

let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is like an optgroup functionality to group your options. Here is a sample of what an optgroup looks like in case you don't know http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup.

There are ways to add an `optgroup` to a dropdown list http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2006/12/27/dropdownlist-with-optgroup.aspx

then you could use it like this

```
ListItem item = new ListItem("some group name", String.Empty);
item.Attributes["optgroup"] = "optgroup";
myDropDown.Items.Add(item);
```

or in your case

```
dropdownlist1.items[i].Attributes["optgroup"] = "optgroup";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
var count = 0;
$('select option').each(function() {
   count++;
   if(count % 5 == 0)
     $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
}):
```

Answer (score -1):

I googled for "disable dropdownlist items" and [the first result](http://forums.asp.net/t/1132654.aspx) provided the exact answers you're looking for.

It's not possible, but there are alternatives.

Comment: On that very same link, user "Henxon" showed it WAS possible, using the same `items[i].Attributes.Add("disabled")` in the answers above on this page.  In order to see the options get disabled, you would need to put it in a `Page_Load` or put the dropdown in a ContentTemplate of an AJAX UpdatePanel if you are doing it dynamically -- but if you are not using an UpdatePanel and you try to do it on the fly, just because the options don't disable, it does not mean it cannot be done - it's just not set up correctly.