# Disable first item in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, visual-web-developer-2010

I'm trying to disable the first item in a drop-down list, which is linked to a "submit" button.
On first loading the page, I want the list to display to the first item in the list, `--Select--` without being able to select it.

Following the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283307/disable-dropdownlist-items), I'm using:

```
dd.Items[0].Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

where `dd` refers to the DropdownList..

This works well but only if I activate it after the submit button is clicked. This means that when the page first loads, I can still select the first item.

If I put the above code in the `Page_Load` method, the list defaults to the next item and `--Select--` is no longer displayed.

Does anyone know a way to have the list continue to display the first item but disable selection of it?

Comment: Where are you disabling the item?  You should do it after you initialize the list (or after you databind, if you're using that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Robert's request, I copied my comment as the answer:

"You could either disable the submit button if the index of your dropdown is 0 (--Select--), or you could check if the index is 0 when the user hits your submit button and just return (or do nothing)."

Comment: Thanks, `if (dd.SelectedIndex != 0)` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="" />   
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Thanks. I already had that but I just wasn't checking for it properly, as per Brett's comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
DropDownList1.Items[0].Enabled = false;
```

or

```
DropDownList1.Items[0].Attributes["style"] = "display:none";
DropDownList1.Items[0].Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
```